# I can't search a Datatable for one row and update row cell data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I’m writing in Inventory program and making my first attempt in utilizing a DataTable.  All I wanted to do is find the right row and be able to update columns like costs, sale price, current inventory.  I’ve tried so many examples that I’ve found but I just can’t seem to make it work.  I have a function that can find current row index but I don’t know how to move to that row and update the data.  I’ve tried selects statements several different ways and haven’t been successful.  I wanna search the Item which is the auto increment record ID.  This can’t be that difficult but I’ve spent three days circling.  If I can get a little advice I would appreciate it.  Thank you

```
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))      ' 1  12
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("ModelStyle", Type.GetType("System.String")) ' 3  2
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")) ' 4  3
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("CoverFinsh", Type.GetType("System.String")) ' 5  4
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Invt.Type", Type.GetType("System.String"))   ' 6  5
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Tag No.", Type.GetType("System.String"))     ' 7  6
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Loc", Type.GetType("System.String"))         ' 8  7
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Curr.Invt.", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))   ' 9  8
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("PO", Type.GetType("System.String"))          ' 10 9
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("PO Date", Type.GetType("System.String"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("CompID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Vendor", Type.GetType("System.String"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Cost", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Retail", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Sale", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Note", Type.GetType("System.String"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Width", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
    InvtTable.Columns.Add("Length", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))     ' 11 10
```

Here are some of the things I’ve tried.
EX 1

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = InvtTable.[Select]("Item = '%0%' ", tbxItemID.Text)
For Each row As DataRow In rows
    MsgBox("here")
Next
```

ex 2

```
Dim matches = From row In InvtTable
                      Let Item = row.Field(Of Int32)("Item")
                      Where Item = Decimal.Parse(tbxItemID.Text)
```

There’s so many more examples for c#.  I wish I would have went that direction but I really don’t wanna start again.
I hope this makes enough sense to help me.  Thank you again

Comment: Don't do this: `Type.GetType("System.Int32")`. Don't use `Type.GetType` unless you have the type name in a variable that you got from somewhere else. If you are using a literal then you should be doing this instead: `GetType(Integer)`. By using a data type, rather than a `String` containing a type name, you get validation by the compiler. Note that this uses the `GetType` operator, rather than the `Type.GetType` method.

Comment: I will change that .  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way with Linq

```
Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(tbxItemID.Text)
Dim row As DataRow = 
    table.AsEnumerable().First(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("Item") = id

' Update row
row.SetField("Cost", 99)
row.SetField("Sale", 199)
```

That said, I would suggest to use plain object, which will make such operations effectively simple

```
Public Class InventoryItem
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property ModelStyle As String
    Public Property CurrentSaldo As Integer
    Public Property CostPrice As Integer
    Public Property SalePrice As Integer
    ' and so on
End Class
```

Than you can populate collection of items from database or file or anywhere else

```
Dim inventory As List(Of Inventory) = LoadFromDatabase()

Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(tbxItemID.Text)
Dim item = inventory.First(Function(item) item.Id = id)

With item
    .CostPrice = 99
    .SalePrice = 199
    .CurrentSaldo -= 1
End With
```

Comment: What you mean by a simple object ?  Is that the InventoryItem class?  Are you creating memory variables rather than using a DataTable ?  I'm not sure I understand everything but I will try it and see if I can get it to work

Comment: I have some work to do but your first example seems to be working .I know little about LINQ.

Comment: @STINGEO, what is the difference between memory variable and DataTable?